# Slicebox 3d image slider not working in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, css, html

For a website i am using this 3d slider
[enter link description here](http://tympanus.net/Development/Slicebox/index.html)

but there is a browser compatibility problem for this slider. it is working well in Chrome in my system.but if i open this in another system with same version of chrome, is not working properly. it shows only simple blur effect.

Answer (score 1):

It's working with chrome, but it fluendly. Ex with me, I test in localhost very good, but when I upload to hosting, it's working very bad.